# Fastest method for checking if a LF is at the end of a large scalar in Perl?

Tags: perl

I've come up with the following to check the final character of a $scaler for a linefeed:

```
if( $buffer !~ /\n$/ ) {
if( substr( $buffer, -1, 1 ) !~ /\n/ ) {
if( substr( $buffer, -1, 1 ) ne '\n' ) {
```

Is there a faster method I could?  The size of the $buffer scalar can get large and I've noticed that the larger it gets, the longer these conditionals take to run.  I do have another scalar containing the length of $buffer, if that would help.

Thanks

The full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl qw();
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday tv_interval );

use constant BUFSIZE => 2 ** 21; # 2MB worked best for me, YMMV.

die "ERROR: Missing filename" if( !$ARGV[0] );

my $top = [gettimeofday];
sysopen( my $fh, $ARGV[0], Fcntl::O_RDONLY | Fcntl::O_BINARY ) or
  die "ERROR: Unable to open $ARGV[0], because $!\n";
open my $output, ">", "/dev/null";  # for 'dummy' processing

my $size = -s $ARGV[0];
my $osiz = $size;
my( $buffer, $offset, $lnCtr ) = ( "", "", 0 );
while( $size ) {
    my $read = sysread( $fh, $buffer, BUFSIZE, length($offset) );
    $size -= $read;
    my @lines = split /\n/, $buffer;
    if( substr( $buffer, -1, 1 ) ne "\n" ) {
        $offset = pop( @lines );
    } else {
        $offset = "";
    }
    for my $line ( @lines ) {
        processLine( \$line );
        $lnCtr++;
    }
    $buffer = $offset if( $offset );
}
close $fh;
print "Processed $lnCtr lines ($osiz bytes) in file: $ARGV[0] in ".
      tv_interval( $top ).
      " secs.\n";
print "Using a buffered read of ".BUFSIZE." bytes.  -  JLB\n";

sub processLine {
    if( ref($_[0]) ) {
        print $output ${$_[0]}."\n";
    } else {
        print $output $_[0]."\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think I've reached that 'point-of-diminishing returns' in my attempts of making this run any faster.  It seems to now be able to read in data as fast as my RAID5 SSDs are able to fetch it.  As you can see, there is a reason I didn't use chomp(), the input can contain hundreds of thousands of linefeeds, which I need to keep to be able to break the lines for processing.

./fastread.pl newdata.log
Processed 516670 lines (106642635 bytes) in file: newdata.log in 0.674738 secs.
Using a buffered read of 2097152 bytes.  -  JLB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl has two string storage formats.

One of the formats uses the same number of bytes (1) to store each possible character the string can contain. Because of that and because Perl keeps track of how many bytes is used by a string, the performance of `substr($x, -1)` on a string in this format does not depend on the the length of the string.

The problem with the aforementioned format is that it can only store a very limited range of characters. It could be used to store the Unicode code points "Eric" and "Éric", but not for "Ελλάδα". When necessary (and even when not necessary), Perl will automatically switch a string's storage format to the other format.

The second format can store any Unicode code point as a character. In fact, it can store any 32-bit or 64-bit value (depending on `perl`'s build settings). The downside is that a variable number of bytes is used to store each character. So even though Perl knows the number of bytes used by the entire string, it doesn't know where any character but the first one starts.* To find the last character, it must scan the entire string.

That said, because of properties of the storage format, it would actually be quite easy to find the last char of a string in constant time.

```
use Inline C => <<'__END_OF_C__';

   # O(1) version of substr($x,-1)
   SV* last_char(SV* sv) {
      STRLEN len;
      const char* s = SvPV(sv, len);

      if (!len)
         return newSVpvn("", 0);

      {
         const U32 utf8 = SvUTF8(sv);
         const char* p = s+len-1;         
         if (utf8) {
            while (p != s && (*p & 0xC0) != 0xC0)
               --p;
         }

         return newSVpvn_utf8(p, s+len-p, utf8);
      }
   }

__END_OF_C__
```

* — It does keep a cache of the couple of char position to byte position mappings.

---

You've shown code which can be cleaned up so you don't even need to check the last char for a newline.

```
sub processLine {
   print $_[0] $_[1];
}


open(my $fh, '<:raw', $ARGV[0])
   or die("Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!\n");

my $buffer = '';
my $lnCtr = 0;
while (1) {
   my $rv = sysread($fh, $buffer, BUFSIZE, length($buffer));
   die $! if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv;

   while ($buffer =~ s/(.*\n)//) {
      processLine($1);
      ++$lnCtr;
   }
}

if (length($buffer)) {
   processLine($output, $buffer);
   ++$lnCtr;
}
```

Notes:

- No need for `sysopen`. `open` is simpler.
- If you pass `$buffer` to `sysread`, it doesn't make sense to use `length($offset)`.
- As you can see, `$offset` and the copying thereof is completely unnecessary.
- Passing a var to a sub does not copy it, so no need to pass a reference.
- If `processLine` doesn't need the newline, use `s/(.*)\n//` instead.

Comment: I see you've added some code, and it changes everything. See the addition I made at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I use $offset for cases where $buffer contains a partial line at the end.  Your second example is doing the same thing, except you modify $buffer on-the-fly rather than splitting into a array as I do.  Tested your second example for speed and its slower than my current version.  I'm assuming that performing a capturing regex for each of the lines is quite a bit slower than Perls built in split()?  Though your earlier inline C code did reduce the end-of-scalar check by a lot - and did make it perform in with consistent execution times.

Comment: @Jim Black, "I use $offset for cases where $buffer contains a partial line at the end", I know, and as you can see by my code, `$offset` and the copying thereof is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Well, it's it's really a bottle neck, you can replace the s/// with a specialised C version. (It's probably the `$1` that's slowing things down.)

Comment: ...using the OOK feature (`perl -MDevel::Peek -E"$_ = 'abc'; s/.//; Dump $_"`), it's very fast to remove from the start of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you concerned about speed?  Is this piece of code in a part of your program that is measurably slow, perhaps profiled with Devel::NYTProf?  If not, then I suggest you go with what is the clearest to read and the most idiomatic, which is probably

```
if( $buffer !~ /\n$/ )
```

Your final version:

```
if( substr( $buffer, -1, 1 ) ne '\n' )
```

would also be a fine choice except for your single-quoting the linefeed, thus giving you a two-character string consisting of a backslash and a lowercase n.  Perhaps you're coming from C where single characters are single quoted and strings are double-quoted?  You want

```
if( substr( $buffer, -1, 1 ) ne "\n" )
```

This version

```
if( substr( $buffer, -1, 1 ) !~ /\n/ )
```

is doing a regex match that it shouldn't be because it's checking a one-character string against a single-character regex.  The next person to read the code will think that's strange and wonder why you'd do that.  Also, back to that speed thing, it's slower to match a string against a regex than just compare against a single character for equality.

Comment: The single quotes, way to much JavaScript in my life lately.  Yes, prof'd several times.  1st and 2nd were nearly identical, third (fixed) is very slightly faster.  Still wondering why it takes longer as the scalar grows - that nagging feeling IS coming from my old C days - as I know it shouldn't be.  Both a 1M and 100M scalar require the same far jumping to pull the char, so I'd think the speed would be identical, as it was in my original C code.  Also tried using a substr with the actual offset of the last character (instead of -1), that was a disaster for performance.

Comment: Doesn't the time spent reading the scalar dwarf the time spent checking for a linefeed?  Maybe you can post all of the code and we can find a better way to solve the problem overall, not just this one linefeed check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Benchmark:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $buffer = 'abc'x10_000_000;
$buffer .= "\n";
my $count = -2;
cmpthese($count, {
    'regex' => sub {
        if ($buffer !~ /\n$/) { }
    },
    'substr + regex' => sub {
        if (substr($buffer, -1, 1) !~ /\n$/) { }
    },
    'substr + ne' => sub {
        if (substr($buffer, -1, 1) ne "\n") { }
    },
    'chomp' => sub {
        if (chomp $buffer) { }
    },
});
```

**Output:**

```
                     Rate substr + regex  substr + ne         regex        chomp
substr + regex  6302468/s             --         -11%          -44%         -70%
substr + ne     7072032/s            12%           --          -37%         -66%
regex          11294695/s            79%          60%            --         -46%
chomp          20910531/s           232%         196%           85%           --
```

`chomp` is certainly the fastest way.

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed since `chomp` changes the buffer. You'll probably still find it the fastest, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect perl is treating the string as utf-8 and has to iterate over the whole thing for some reason.

You could temporarily switch to byte semantics to see if the char on the end is a newline.

See docs for Perl's [bytes pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/bytes.html) and [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Byte-and-Character-Semantics).

Comment: I'm using<p> sysopen( my $fh, $ARGV[0], Fcntl::O_RDONLY | Fcntl::O_BINARY )<p>and<p>sysread( $fh, $buffer, BUFSIZE, length($offset) );<p> to pull in the data.  Can I assume that the O_BINARY switch would prevent the utf-8 semantics?

Comment: I think O_BINARY only controls CR/LF translation semantics, and has no effect on unicode translation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html). Chomp will return the number of EOL characters removed from the end of a line:

```
if ( chomp $buffer ) {
    print "You had an LF on the end of \$buffer";
}
```

Of course, chomp removes the NL characters it counted.